# find parent node in treeview

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Im using treeview in asp.net

how can i check if parent contains childnodes in treeview selected node changed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to look if the parent of the selected node contains other children nodes, it is safe to say

```
bool ContainsOtherChildren = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parnet.ChildNodes.Count > 1;
```

since you know that it already has at least one child node (the selected one)

I would however make another check if there is indeed a parent such as

```
if(treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent != null)
{
   ContainsOtherChildren = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parnet.ChildNodes.Count > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check All the child pointer values, whether is it NULL or not.
>
> If all child pointer value is NULL , you can ensure  that the parent does not have any child.

Comment: Sorry , I posting my c logic code. 
<code> 

struct tree
{
        int node  ;
         struct tree *left ;
         struct tree *right;
} ; 

struct *p; 

if (p->left !=NULL && p->right !=NULL ) 

Then p will not be having any child. 



</code>